# A substitute to (think of a way)

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

Let's suppose in a meeting, a couple of co-workes are discussiong about an issue and are going to find out a solution to it! One of them brings up a solution. The other person who's playing the leading role at the meeting raises sole objections to that solution and says:

> - Can you **think of** any other way?

Would it indicate the same message naturally and idiomatically to say:

> - Can you **come up with** any othe way?
> - Does any other way **crosse your mind**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ***come up with*** is a substitute for *think of* in this context. It won't work in every case, and the reverse won't always work, but here it does.

There's a slight difference. If you want people to hold something in mind - "think of a number, any number" - then you want *think*. Also, *come up* tends to imply that people are being novel or creative, or having to engage their critical faculties; *think* can include just remembering something.

***Cross your mind*** is a different matter. It implies that it is involuntary, like a memory occurring to your or an idea striking you without you being an active participant. It could work, depending on what impression you want to give.